# iOS MagicalRecord--Can I change the MR/CD setup scheme after the fact?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I've got a little app using Core Data via MagicalRecord that is working fine, in its rudimentary fashion, thanks largely to the help I've found here.

Now, I've discovered that I need to add a new attribute on an entity in my data model. And, belatedly, I've also discovered that I should have used the MagicalRecord method "setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed" instead of the plain Jane "setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:"

I understand that the automigrating option will take care of the lightweight migration (my first) automatically.

Before I get myself into real trouble, can I simply change that one line of code in the AppDelegate from:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
```

to:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
```

Be gentle with me--in all the tuts and research I've done, the issue was never addressed up front, I mean, making sure all possible attributes have been thought of and included when creating the data model and before deciding on which MR option to use. I'm sure this gotcha would have been obvious to a more experienced programmer, but it wasn't to me. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be just fine. All the auto migrating method does is set some configuration options to the stack setup. The rest of the initialization is identical to the basic setup.

However, if you're using your app in development, I would also recommend just deleting the old version of the store and starting over. This is commonly how I work in development when I am rapidly updating or modifying the core data model for an app.

Comment: Thank you very much, both for the answer, and for MagicalRecord! It's a tremendous help getting into Core Data. If I may ask, how would I delete the old version of the store?

Comment: There are multiple options. The easiest way is to just delete the application from the simulator/device. But you can also delete just your `MyDatabase.sqlite` file.

Comment: MagicalRecord has an option to automatically delete incompatible stores for you. Have a look at the headers to see what the option is (I don't remember the actual name off the top of my head)

Comment: Thanks @Sandro. I'm going to ask what may be an ultra dumb question here: Am I assuming too much to think that with MagicalRecord all I had to do was to change that one line of code mentioned above? Or do I also need to create a new model and follow other steps specified for lightweight migration without MagicalRecord. Forgive my noobiness, but I just tried the adding the one attribute, recreating the subclass and  changing the setup method as described above. Now the new attribute seems to be missing, and I don't know if it's being created at all. Once again, all help much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry @casa. I didn't see your comment until after I posted my comment. Please feel free to put me back on the rails regarding the above mentioned quandary. Thanks!

Comment: @Sandro-- OK, I went back and reviewed a CD migration tutorial (Simon Allardice on Lynda). From that, and from the much appreciated help here, I: 1) Added a new version of the data model, 2) Added my new attribute to the new version, 3) Selected (green-checked) the new version, 4) Changed from the "setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed" method to the "setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed" method in my AppDelegate. So far everything seems perfect--No crashes, and I can see and use the new attribute! Thanks again, amigos!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. As @casademora said, if your still in development and your app has not yet been published to the AppStore, you don't need to setup a new version of your model. But if you already launched it, you have to do it exactly the way you did it.

Comment: No, it's a long way from the App Store right now, although I hope to get it there at some point. Right now, I'm ecstatic and grateful to you guys that it works as well as it does. But I'm a little confused. Can I delete the old data model after the successful migration? And can I use the newest model as a base for creating a new model? I'm thinking of using some new entities to pre-populate my tableview.